# Cannot read property '$ngoptionlabel' of null when using ng-select

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I'm using `ng-select` to display data which my app has retrieved from an API, but although the data is successfully retrieved nothing is shown in the dropdown. It just says "No items found." In the console I have the following error:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '$ngoptionlabel' of null`

This is my typescript code:

```js
// in a service, using HttpClient
this.http.get<string[]>(url);
```

```js
// in a component, using the service injected in
data: string[] = [];
this.service.get()
   .subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data; // data contains values as expected
      // other logic
   });
```

In my template, I pass `this.data` to `ng-select`.

```html
<ng-select [items]="data"
           [multiple]="true"
           [closeOnSelect]="false"
           [searchable]="true">
</ng-select>
```

I thought the error sounded like it might be to do with the `bindLabel` option, but I'm not using it. What does the error mean, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error means that one of the items in the array being displayed is `null`. To solve this, filter `null`s out of the array before passing it to `ng-select`. In the case where the data is being retrieved from an API, you can use the rxjs `map` operator to achieve this.

```js
this.http
   .get<string[]>(url)
   .pipe(
      map(data => data.filter(x => x != null))
   );
```